# Use the numbers 1-9 to equal 1150

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Not sure if this is too hard, but it's a more or less simple math puzzle. Use the numbers

> $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$

to get an answer of 1150. You can use the operators

> $+,-,*,/,\hat{}$

You can use each number only once, each operator can be used as many times as you want. You can also round to the nearest 10.
You also cannot put the numbers together(e.g. you can't do 1234 or such, each has to be a separate number). In addition, all numbers must be used.

Note: This is solvable, no lateral thinking needed. Pure calculations.

Comment: What is the operator $**$?

Comment: can we use ( )?

Comment: @randal'thor it's the exponent

Comment: @gstats yeah that's fine

Comment: There are so many possible answers, how are you going to judge?

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal I actually didn't expect there to be more than one. Generally, though, you just go by whichever gives the best/most relevant answer in the quickest time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My answer is

> $(((7+3)*4)+6)*(5**2)+(9-(1+8)) = 1150$

Details:

> $(((7+3)*4)+6)*(5**2)+(9-(1+8))= ((10*4)+6)*25 + 0 = 46*25 = 1150$

Comment: Wow, that's impressive. I actually got an answer of around 1154, which then rounded to 1150. This definitely fits, though.

Answer (score 74):

Here's an answer which

> doesn't change the order of the digits, and doesn't even use any operations other than $\times$ and $+$:
>
>  $1\times (2+3)\times (4+5+(6+7)\times (8+9))$

Comment: The best as of now :)

Answer (score 22):

I have a solution that doesn't change the order of the digits.

> $1+2^3+4^5+6\times 7+8\times 9$
>
> and round to the nearest multiple of 10.

Comment: That is...really impressive. *mind explodes*

Comment: Is order of operations followed, or do you go from left to right?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Normal operator precedence :-)

Answer (score 10):

Bit late, just for fun

> Prime factoring gives $1150=2\times5^2\times23$
>  So sub in for those four values $\frac{6}{3}\times5^\frac{4}{2}\times(9+8+7-1)=1150$

Comment: I always upvote posts when they give a correct answer, even if it's late. :P I'm actually out of daily votes right now, but I will upvote it in 7 hours

Comment: This is cool. @Saiid I'll do the honours.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal coolio.

Answer (score 9):

Answer:

> $(6**4)-(2**7)-9-8-5+3+1$

This gives

> $1296-128-17-1=1150$, exactly as required.

I found this by

> more or less using a greedy algorithm: $6^4$ was the closest perfect power I found to $1150$, and subtracting $1150$ from it gives $146$, to which the closest perfect power I found was $2^7$; then after that it's a simple addition/subtraction game.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know the site accepted more than 1 answer.

Comment: Thumbs up for the exact answer. He forced me to search for the perfect equation. Likewise with you @gstats

Comment: I'll give a +1 here because it _is_ cleaner than gstats's, however they did give a correct answer before you. Granted, this is partly my fault for not saying exactly what I was looking for the first time.

Comment: @Saiid Just edited to add some explanation of my method, how I actually found this solution.

Comment: @randal'thor yup, I saw it. It was interesting.

Answer (score 6):

> $(1 \times 2^3 \times 4 \times 5 - 6) \times 7 + 8 \times 9$
>  and
>  ($-1 + 2 \times 3 \times 4) \times 5 \times 6 \times \frac{7 + 8}{9}$

also preserve the order of digits, and give exactly 1150

Answer (score 4):

One answer is

> $1234+56/7-89$.

This gives

> $1153$, and you said rounding to the nearest 10 was allowed.

Another answer is

> $6789/5-213+4$.

This gives

> $1148.8$, which again is correct when rounding to the nearest 10.

Comment: ah i didn't think about a solution like that. i should have put they cannot be put together

Comment: @Saiid OK, added a better answer now.

Answer (score 4):

*It's now updated to meet the edited question :)*
Solution

> $2^7 * (1 + 8 + 4 + 5 - 9) -(6/3) = 1150$

@MackTuesday Thanks for pointing out the huge calculation mistake in my previous answer, I've gotten rid of it.

Comment: edited to include something I should have put before that makes this invalid

Comment: Um... 8^4 = 4096.

Comment: Damn. I missed it. I'll have to edit my answer then. No longer useful.

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

> $2 * (1 + 4) * 5 * (7 * 8 - 3 * 9 - 6) = 1150$

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution based on breaking 1150 into

> $900 + 250$, or $30 ^ 2 + 2 * 5 ^ 3$

From that it was pretty easy to use each digit once

> $2 *5 ^ 3 + (6 * (9 - 4))^{8 - 7 + 1}$

Comment: nice! will upvote in 5 hours after my daily count resets

Answer (score 4):

Here are 100 answers calculated using [this little Haskell program](https://gist.github.com/hoheinzollern/1d0b281d01d1cea65aa0b8c93f098f6b) that I wrote:

> $(9 - (6 - 8) \cdot 7) \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 + 4) \cdot 5)$ 
>  $((8 - 6) \cdot 7 + 9) \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 + 4) \cdot 5)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8 \cdot 9 + 5 - 7$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8 \cdot 9 - 7 + 5$ 
>  $5 - (7 - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8 \cdot 9)$ 
>  $5 - 7 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8 \cdot 9$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8 \cdot 9 - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $9 \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8) + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $9 \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9 \cdot 8 - 7 + 5$ 
>  $5 - (7 - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9 \cdot 8)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9 \cdot 8 + 5 - 7$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9 \cdot 8 - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $5 - 7 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ 
>  $8 \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9) + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $8 \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $9 \cdot 8 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8 - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $8 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9 - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $9 \cdot 8 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 8 + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $8 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot 9 + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $8 \cdot 9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) - 7 + 5$ 
>  $5 - (7 - 8 \cdot 9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6))$ 
>  $8 \cdot 9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) + 5 - 7$ 
>  $8 \cdot 9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $5 - 7 + 8 \cdot 9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot (8 \cdot 9) + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) \cdot (8 \cdot 9) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (8 \cdot 9) + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot 9 \cdot 8 + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot 8 \cdot 9 + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $9 \cdot 8 \cdot (6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (8 \cdot 9) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot 9 \cdot 8 - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot 8 \cdot 9 - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $9 \cdot 8 \cdot (6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $(6 \cdot 9 - 8) \cdot (5 \cdot 7 - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4))$ 
>  $(8 - 6 \cdot 9) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 \cdot 7)$ 
>  $(5 \cdot 7 - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (9 \cdot 6 - 8)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 \cdot 7) \cdot (8 - 9 \cdot 6)$ 
>  $(8 - 9 \cdot 6) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 \cdot 7)$ 
>  $(9 \cdot 6 - 8) \cdot (5 \cdot 7 - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4))$ 
>  $(9 - (6 - 8) \cdot 7) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) \cdot 5$ 
>  $(9 - (6 - 8) \cdot 7) \cdot 5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) \cdot 5 \cdot (9 - (6 - 8) \cdot 7)$ 
>  $(9 - (6 - 8) \cdot 7) \cdot (5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4))$ 
>  $(9 - 7 \cdot (6 - 8)) \cdot (5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4))$ 
>  $((8 - 6) \cdot 7 + 9) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) \cdot 5$ 
>  $((8 - 6) \cdot 7 + 9) \cdot 5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) \cdot 5 \cdot ((8 - 6) \cdot 7 + 9)$ 
>  $(9 + (8 - 6) \cdot 7) \cdot (5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4))$ 
>  $(7 \cdot (8 - 6) + 9) \cdot (5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4))$ 
>  $(7 \cdot 5 - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (6 \cdot 9 - 8)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 7 \cdot 5) \cdot (8 - 6 \cdot 9)$ 
>  $(7 \cdot 8 + (6 \cdot 9 + 5)) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(8 \cdot 7 + 5 + 6 \cdot 9) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(8 \cdot 7 + 6 \cdot 9 + 5) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(5 + 6 \cdot 9 + 8 \cdot 7) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(6 \cdot 9 - 8) \cdot (7 \cdot 5 - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4))$ 
>  $(8 - 6 \cdot 9) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 7 \cdot 5)$ 
>  $(6 \cdot 9 + (7 \cdot 8 + 5)) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(9 \cdot 6 + 5 + 7 \cdot 8) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(9 \cdot 6 + 7 \cdot 8 + 5) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(5 + 7 \cdot 8 + 9 \cdot 6) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (8 \cdot 9) - 7 + 5$ 
>  $5 - (7 - (6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (8 \cdot 9))$ 
>  $(6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (8 \cdot 9) + 5 - 7$ 
>  $5 - 7 + (6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) \cdot (8 \cdot 9)$ 
>  $8 \cdot 9 \cdot (6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) + (5 - 7)$ 
>  $8 \cdot 9 \cdot (6 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)) - (7 - 5)$ 
>  $(8 - 6 \cdot 9) \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 7) \cdot 5)$ 
>  $(8 - 9 \cdot 6) \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 7) \cdot 5$ 
>  $(8 - 9 \cdot 6) \cdot 5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 7)$ 
>  $(1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 7) \cdot 5 \cdot (8 - 9 \cdot 6)$ 
>  $(8 - 9 \cdot 6) \cdot (5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 7))$ 
>  $(6 \cdot 9 - 8) \cdot ((7 - (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)) \cdot 5)$ 
>  $(9 \cdot 6 - 8) \cdot (7 - (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)) \cdot 5$ 
>  $(9 \cdot 6 - 8) \cdot 5 \cdot (7 - (1 + 2 + 3 - 4))$ 
>  $(7 - (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)) \cdot 5 \cdot (9 \cdot 6 - 8)$ 
>  $(9 \cdot 6 - 8) \cdot (5 \cdot (7 - (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)))$ 
>  $(5 \cdot 8 + 6) \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9 + 7)$ 
>  $(6 \cdot 7 + 8) \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9 + 5)$ 
>  $(7 \cdot 8 - 6) \cdot ((1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9 + 5)$ 
>  $(5 + (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9) \cdot (8 \cdot 7 - 6)$ 
>  $(8 \cdot 7 - 6) \cdot (5 + (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9)$ 
>  $(7 + (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9) \cdot (8 \cdot 5 + 6)$ 
>  $(6 + 8 \cdot 5) \cdot (7 + (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9)$ 
>  $((1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9 + 5) \cdot (7 \cdot 6 + 8)$ 
>  $(8 + 7 \cdot 6) \cdot (5 + (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9)$ 
>  $(9 / (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 8 \cdot 7 + 6) \cdot 5$ 
>  $(9 / (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 7 \cdot 8 + 6) \cdot 5$ 
>  $(8 \cdot 7 \cdot (9 / (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)) + 6) \cdot 5$ 
>  $((1 + 2 + 3 - 4) \cdot 9 + 7) \cdot (5 \cdot 8 + 6)$ 
>  $(5 \cdot 8 + 6) \cdot (9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) + 7)$ 
>  $(7 + 9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)) \cdot (6 + 5 \cdot 8)$ 
>  $(9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) + 5) \cdot (6 \cdot 7 + 8)$ 
>  $(8 + 6 \cdot 7) \cdot (9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4) + 5)$ 
>  $(5 + 9 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)) \cdot (8 + 6 \cdot 7)$ 
>  $(7 - (1 + 2 + 3 - 4)) \cdot ((6 \cdot 9 - 8) \cdot 5)$

Feel free to edit this answer if it feels too long, and to run the program changing take 100 with whatever number of answers you might like to find out.

Comment: Well...that's one way of doing it. What language is that btw? I can't read it

Comment: The language is [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), it's a functional programming language so much closer to math than the average, and good for expressing this sort of problems. This puzzle is combinatorial so I thought it would be cool to find a solution using programming :)

Comment: Great one! Welcome to puzzling

Comment: Oh, cool. I've never heard of that one before.

Comment: I see why this question is on hold...

Comment: Is it not fair to find the solution programmatically? I'm new to forum. I just saw the question and thought it was interesting to solve this way. The program is not completely trivial to formulate.

Answer (score 2):

> $(9+8+6)*5*(7+3)*(4-2-1)$

The trick I used was to express 1150 as

> a product of factors, and then try and find individual factors. Here I saw $1150 = 23*5*10*1$.

Comment: interesting. lel

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine, uses every number and doesn't round.

> $(((9^4)/3)-1)/2 + (7*8) + 6 - 5 = 1150$

Answer (score 2):

> $$1 + 2 + 3 \times 6 + 4 \times 5 \times 7 \times 8 + 9 = 1150$$

Closed in on it as follows:

> $$\begin{align}1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9 &= 62880 \\1*2*3*4*5/6*7*8*9 &= 10080 \\1*2/3*4*5/6*7*8*9 &= 1120 \\1*2*4*5/6*7*8*3+9 &= 1129 \\1*4*5*7*8+9+6+2+3 &= 1140 \\1*4*5*7*8+9+6+2*3 &= 1141 \\1*4*5*7*8+9+6*2+3 &= 1144 \\1*4*5*7*8+9+6*3+2 &= 1149\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

By now it's been done to death, but here's my variant. I tried to do it in reverse order of digits, but failed. Each grouping is in reverse order just to sort of succeed. :)

> $9\cdot 5+ 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 3-4+2-1$

With parentheses for clarity.

> $(9\cdot 5)+ (8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 3)-(4-2+1)$

I did succeed at keeping it all in one line, so that's a plus.

Comment: It has been done to death. lol. I never thought a puzzle of mine would get this popular

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt

> $(8\times7\times5\times4)+(9\times3)+(6-2-1)$
> $=1120+27+3$
> $=1150$

Answer (score 1):

> (9 + 1) * 5 * (((7 * ((3 / ((6 ^ 2 / 4) – 8) ))) +2)

Answer (score 1):

I've got this for an answer:

> (9*8*7*2)+(3*(6+5+4-1))

Can also be changed into:

> ((5+4)*8*7*2)+(3*(6+9-1))

It uses only + - and * .