# Use numbers 1-9 to yield 300000

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Inspired by [@Saiid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30376/saiid)'s earlier [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43639).

Using $+,-,×,÷,$ exponents and factorials, use all the numbers $1-9$ (once and only once each) to generate $300 000$.
Don't compose numbers from their digits, just operate on them.

Bonus points for keeping digits in order.
Bonus points for using all operators.

Will accept answer that I find most interesting after 24 hours.

Comment: All numbers only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just a guest for now but felt like showing my answer with all bonuses.

> $(1+2)((3!+4)^{\frac{5}{(6-7)(8-9)}})$
>  $3×10^{5/1}$
>  $3$e$5$
>  $300000$

Comment: Gorgeous simplicity; well done!

Answer (score 4):

Time to get 300,000, now that the body matches the title. I tried to get something fancy like my original 30,000 answer but gave up after a while:

> $(3×(4+6)^5 + 7 + 9 - (8×2))/1!$

It ticks all the boxes, but in a pretty soulless way I'll admit.

BONUS: My previous answer to get 30,000

Here goes:

> $(((9^5) + (3^6) + (8×7×4)) / 2) - 1 = 30000$

(I can't kill spoilers on more than the first line for some reason so I edited to omit the breakdown)

EDIT: Thanks to Jonathan for teaching me how to spoiler better so I could put in the breakdown

> $((59049 + 729 + 224)/2) - 1$
> $(60002/2) -1$
> $30001 -1$

Comment: I just noticed you can make this use all operators very easily using the fact that $1!=1$ (or even $2!=2$).

Comment: Oh, and for multiline spoilers end your lines with two spaces.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan, the degenerate cases of ÷1, ×1, 1! and 2! I deem less interesting ;)

Answer (score 4):

$300,000$ is such a

> nice round number in decimal that this is particularly easy to do with $1-9$ in order:
>
>  $(1+2+3+4)^5\times(6(7-8)+9)$

Answer (score 3):

$300,000$ can be reached using

> two powers, and with digits in order, by $\dfrac{1(2^3)4(5^6)}{7+8}\times 9$

Comment: Second runner up for being so darn cute.

Answer (score 1):

Transforming my 30,000 answer for 300,000 that also uses all operators:

> $(6!+(7+8)\times(\frac93-1))\times (4\times 5)^2$
>
>  $=((6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2)+15\times 2)\times 20^2$
>  $=(720+30)\times 400$
>  $=750\times 400$
>  $=300000$

Here is an answer (to the original 30,000) using all operators:

> $(6!+\frac{8\times 4 + 7 - 9}{1})\times 2^3\times 5$
>
>  $=((6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2)+\frac{32 + 7 - 9}{1})\times 8\times 5$
>  $=(720+30)\times 40$
>  $=750\times 40$
>  $=30000$

Comment: First runner up for having the largest n!

Answer (score 1):

Here goes:

> This is the answer to number 30000
>  $((8+2)^4)\times3+(9+5)-(1+6+7)$

After op has changed their number to 300000

> $((9+1)^5)\times3+(4-\frac{6}{2})-(8-7)! $

Motive:

> $(100000\times3)+1-1$

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's still interested in the earlier target of $30,000$, I found an expression that seems more interesting than mine for $300,000$.

> $30000=3\times 10^4=3\times (2\times 5)^4=5^4\times (2^4\times 3)=625\times 48$ so
>
>  $30000=1(2+3)^4(5(6+7)-8-9)$

Answer (score 0):

My original solution when forming the question:

> $9!+((1+6^2)-3×7×8)×4×5!$

Which I thought a bit cute.

Answer (score -1):

> $(1^2)+(3*4^5)-6-7-8-9-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9+(1*2)$

That's my answer.

Comment: "use all the numbers 1−9 (once and only once each)"

Comment: If I did mental math right, this makes 952. Even if I made a mistake, I'm pretty sure it's not 300000.

Comment: It's actually 3,000. But as you said not 300,000 and too many numbers.

Comment: Ops, I got wrong, i'll change soon. i'm sorry